# Intuition behind multiplication in joint probability

Tags: probability, statistics, intuition, conditional-probability, bayesian

[image]

In this example, If temp = high then there is chance for weather being sunny is 60%. And P(temp = high) = 30%.
The highlighted box represents days with high temperature and weather being sunny. In other words, P(temp=high ∩ weather = sunny) = **60% * 30%** = 18%
As far as I know we multiply to get joint probability. So here I am trying to find intersection which is joint probability and I am doing multiplication operation.

Now, My question is, Why we need to do multiplication here? From kindergarten multiplication has been known as A*B. where A is added B times to itself. Which clearly does not signify the relationship of intersection. What I am missing here?

Comment: Perhaps [this article](https://www.themathdoctors.org/why-do-we-add-or-multiply-in-probability/) might be helpful to develop your intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is just by the definition of conditional probability that:

$$\mathsf P(\text{high_temp}\cap\text{sunny})=\mathsf P(\text{high_temp})\cdot\mathsf P(\text{sunny}\mid\text{high_temp})$$

Or in terms of generic events $A,B$:$$\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(B\mid A)$$

Or with a little rearrangement: $\mathsf P(B\mid A)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(A)}$

That is, the conditional probability of $B$ when given $A$ is just the measure of the probability for the intersection ($A\cap B$) relative to that for the given event ($A$).

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I know that definition. But, I want to know why I am using multiplication operation to find answer of (∩)? Why I can't relate concept of general multiplication with this one?